# Advanced Reference qualifier on field not working as expected

Tags: servicenow

on my PDI (Utah) I have a script include that I've been using to test reference qualifiers on a field.
The script simply returns a query that, in theory, should be used to filter a a user list according to their company.

This is the script include:

```
var GetCallersforIncident = Class.create();
GetCallersforIncident.prototype = {
    initialize: function()
    {
    },
    getCallers: function()
    {
        return 'companyIN4b7d13f03710200044e0bfc8bcbe5db6';
    },
    type: 'GetCallersforIncident'
};
```

the company with sys_id `4b7d13f03710200044e0bfc8bcbe5db6` exists and there are a numbers of users attached to it.
The field on which the filter is being applied is on table Incident and is `caller_id`. Attached is a screenshot of the reference specification.
[image: field dictionary reference specification]

When I open an incident and click on the caller_id magnifiying glass, a user list opens but it's empty. Evidently the filter is not working. Any clues?

thank you.

Comment: I copied your script include and reference qualifier to a reference field on a custom table and it works fine, I tested it on the incident.caller_id field and it also works fine (20 user records returned).

Are you able to show your full script include record (screenshot or xml record)?